# Median Filter FSM Modelling

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, state-machines

I'm trying to build a median filter in Verilog using a comparator to sort out the highest pixel value and erase it, then sort out the next highest etc. until I have only 5 pixels left (I'm treating groups of 9 pixels) and the highest value of those is the median. I modelled this problem by having a initial state, one state to receive pixels and 5 states to find max. (Each state sorts between less bytes so at the end of my fifth state I'll have the median). Both code snippet below shows what I described above.
Sorting module:

```
module MED #(parameter WIDTH = 8,
            parameter NUM = 9)
            (input [WIDTH-1:0]DI,
             input DSI, BYP, CLK,
             output [WIDTH-1:0] DO);

logic [WIDTH-1:0] R[0:NUM-1];
wire [WIDTH-1:0]MIN, MAX;
wire [WIDTH-1:0]D1, D2;

MCE #(.WIDTH(WIDTH)) MCE1(
    .A(DO),
    .B(R[NUM-2]),
    .MIN(MIN),
    .MAX(MAX)

);
assign D2 = (BYP) ? R[NUM-2] : MAX;
assign D1 = (DSI) ? DI : MIN;
assign DO = R[NUM-1];

         always_ff @(posedge CLK)
     begin
         R <= {D1, R[0:NUM-2]};     

         R[NUM-1] <= D2;         
     end

endmodule
```

Whole filter:

```
module MEDIAN #(parameter WIDTH = 8)
        (input [WIDTH-1:0]DI,
         input DSI, nRST, CLK,
         output [WIDTH-1:0] DO,
         output logic DSO);

     logic BYP;

     MED #(.WIDTH(WIDTH), .NUM(9)) MED1(
         .DI(DI),
         .DSI(DSI),
         .CLK(CLK),
         .BYP(BYP),
         .DO(DO)
     );

     //Compteur mod 8
     //Le clk de sortie sera utilisé par la machine à états finis.
     logic [3:0]counter;

     always_ff @(posedge CLK or negedge nRST)
     begin
         if(!nRST)
             counter <= 4'd0;

         else if(counter == 4'b1000)
             counter <= 4'd0;

         else
             counter <=counter+1;
     end



    //Machine à états finis

    logic [2:0] state;  
    localparam INIT = 3'd0;
    localparam S0 = 3'd1;
    localparam S1 = 3'd2;
    localparam S2 = 3'd3;
    localparam S3 = 3'd4;
    localparam S4 = 3'd5;
    localparam S5 = 3'd6;


    always_ff @(posedge CLK or negedge nRST)
    begin

    if(!nRST)
        state <= INIT;
    else
        case(state)
            INIT: if(DSI)
            begin
                counter <= 4'd0;
                state <= S0;    
            end

            S0  : if(counter == 4'd8)
            begin
                counter <= 4'd0;
                state <= S1;
            end

            S1  : if(counter == 4'd8)
                state <= S2;

            S2  : if(counter == 4'd8)
                state <= S3;

            S3  : if(counter == 4'd8)
                state <= S4;

            S4  : if(counter == 4'd8)
                state <= S5;

            S5  :
                state <= INIT;
        endcase

    end

    always_comb
    begin
        if(state == INIT)
            DSO = 0;

        else if(state == S0)
            BYP = 1;
            if(counter == 8)
                BYP = 0;

        else if(state == S1)
            BYP = (counter == 4'd8) ? 1 : 0;

        else if(state == S2)
            BYP = (counter > 4'd6) ? 1 : 0;

        else if(state == S3)
            BYP = (counter > 4'd5) ? 1 : 0;

        else if(state == S4)
            BYP = (counter > 4'd4) ? 1 : 0;

        else if(state == S5)
        begin
            BYP = 0;
            DSO = 1;
        end
    end


endmodule
```

This is the waveform I'm getting. Top row are my pixel values, bottom row is my current state and above that is my counter. Above the counter is my bypass signal, which would erase the max value and proceed to sort the next highest. What I wanted to have is have bypass set for when I have counter = 8 and state 2, then bypass set for counter = 7 and 8 when in state 3...

[image: Waveform]

Is there any way to fix this or should I model my FSM differently (I'd like to keep the principle of sorting by highest value and erasing them, though).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a mistake:

```
    else if(state == S0)
        BYP = 1;
        if(counter == 8)
            BYP = 0;
```

Note that the `else` that follows this gets matched up with the **second** `if`, not the first one!

A `begin`/`end` pair would fix this, but based on the indentation and the general structure of that block, you probably wanted something more like:

```
    else if (state == S0)
        BYP = (counter == 4'd8) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Dave! That does the trick of having my bypass signal placed in the right count as I described above. However, I still have problems showing the median. It seems the number 0x24 gets lost in the middle of the sorting process and never shows up again... It seems my bypass signal might last too long when it is supposed to be one pulse and I end up erasing more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

More some notes than answers (but to long to be just comments) - what is a bit strang is that you have two always blocks which assign to counter. The first block does the counting while the following block in FSM actually write to counter sometimes as well. E.g. here:

```
S0  : if(counter == 4'd8)
begin
   counter <= 4'd0;
   state <= S1;
end
```

Furthermore is you counter counting to 8 which implies it actually is counter modulo 9 if I am not mistaken while your comment says that it should be "mod 8". And in your always_comb block you sometimes use "==" and sometimes "<" to compare the counting variable with your "thresholds". Is that intended?

Sometimes simplifying the code can help to find the issue. If I am not mistaken one could transform your code like this (only from scratch without testing/debugging!):

```
module MEDIAN #(parameter WIDTH = 8)
    (input [WIDTH-1:0]DI,
     input DSI, nRST, CLK,
     output [WIDTH-1:0] DO,
     output logic DSO);

 logic BYP;

 MED #(.WIDTH(WIDTH), .NUM(9)) MED1(
     .DI(DI),
     .DSI(DSI),
     .CLK(CLK),
     .BYP(BYP),
     .DO(DO)
 );


//Machine à états finis

logic [2:0] counter;
logic [2:0] state;  
localparam INIT = 3'd0;
localparam S0 = 3'd1;
localparam S1 = 3'd2;
localparam S2 = 3'd3;
localparam S3 = 3'd4;
localparam S4 = 3'd5;
localparam S5 = 3'd6;


always_ff @(posedge CLK or negedge nRST)
begin

if(!nRST)
    state   <= INIT;
    counter <= 3'd0;
else
    counter <= DSI ? 3'd0 : counter+1;

    if(state == INIT)     state <= DSI ? S0 : INIT;
    else if(state == S5)  state <= INIT;
    else                  state <= state + (counter == 4'd8);
end

always_comb
begin
    case(state)
        INIT:    {BYP, DSO} = 2'b00;
        S0  :    {BYP, DSO} = (counter == 4'd8) ? 2'b00 : 2'b10;
        S1  :    {BYP, DSO} = (counter == 4'd8) ? 2'b00 : 2'b10;
        S2  :    {BYP, DSO} = (counter == 4'd6) ? 2'b00 : 2'b10;
        S3  :    {BYP, DSO} = (counter == 4'd5) ? 2'b00 : 2'b10;
        S4  :    {BYP, DSO} = (counter == 4'd4) ? 2'b00 : 2'b10;
        S5  :    {BYP, DSO} = 2'b01;
        default: {BYP, DSO} = 2'b00;
    endcase
end
```

Maybe you can use this as an inspiration. There is still some redundancy in this example. My personal recommendation is to avoid writing to a variable from blocks and to thread "cases" as multiplexer: assign a valid value for each case to each variable they "write to".